# Copy large files (over 2 GB) in PHP

Tags: php, file, copy

I need to copy some big file (6 GB) via PHP. How can I do that?
The `Copy()` function can't do it.

I am using PHP 5.3 on Windows 32/64.

Comment: Why cant `copy` do that? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Copy to where? Can the destination filesystem support 6GB files?

Comment: I thought that PHP has some limits (> 2 GB) http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php#69001 copy() get only a few MB from file, no error. There is also problem with filesize() ... yes, destination filesystem is NTFS

Comment: @Gordon Because copy() seems to revert the internal offset position back to 0 after every 4 GiB, even on 64-bit builds of PHP on 64-bit systems.

Comment: @StanE that seems to be file system related. See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=81145.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This should do it.

```
function chunked_copy($from, $to) {
    # 1 meg at a time, you can adjust this.
    $buffer_size = 1048576; 
    $ret = 0;
    $fin = fopen($from, "rb");
    $fout = fopen($to, "w");
    while(!feof($fin)) {
        $ret += fwrite($fout, fread($fin, $buffer_size));
    }
    fclose($fin);
    fclose($fout);
    return $ret; # return number of bytes written
}
```

Comment: If $from is a url, then your buffer size is limited to 8k, making this process inefficient.

Comment: for some reason it ends before coping the whole file

Answer (score 2):

If `copy` doesnt work, you can try with

- [stream_copy_to_stream — Copies data from one stream to another](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-copy-to-stream.php)

**Example**

```
stream_copy_to_stream(
    fopen('/path/to/input/file.txt', 'r'),
    fopen('/path/to/output/file.txt', 'w+')
);
```

Also see https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=81145

Comment: You should probably fclose these afterwards unless your script execution stops immediately afterwards.

Comment: I tried this on a 64-bit Windows 10 build with 64-bit build of PHP 8.0.7. stream_copy_to_stream() seems to have the same problem with file sizes over 4 GiB. After ever 4 GiB the file contents repeat.

Answer (score 2):

Recent versions of PHP copy files with chunks so today you could use php `copy()` function safely

Comment: What does "recent" mean here. This answer would be much better with a version number...

Comment: No, I don't think that this is correct. I am using PHP 8.0.7 compiled as 64-bit (so it uses 8-byte integers internally). copy() still doesn't support copying files larger than 4 GiB. It does copy them, but it starts to write from offset 0 after ever 4 GiB.

Comment: PHP 8.1.9 stucks on copying by `copy()` of 4GB on ~2.7GB

Answer (score 1):

You could use `exec()` if it's a linux machine.

```
$srcFile = escapeshellarg($pathToSrcFile);
$trgFile = escapeshellarg($pathToTrgFile);

exec("cp $srcFile $trgFile");
```

Comment: .. windows, but I prefer PHP way, if it's possible.

Comment: @Adrian Yes, but then you need to use 'copy' command, not 'cp'.

Comment: true, I assumed this is understood

Comment: To be honest, from all the answers this is the only one that's sane.

Comment: @yi_H: I don't know. If PHP `copy` "can't do" it, then Windows `copy` can't either. So then you start looking at transfer limits (possibly filesize limits on the destination media), and end up looking at chunked transfers.. and Dogbert's answer.

Comment: If there is a filesize limit, how would chunked transfer work?

Comment: Why would you prefer PHP way? What's the advantage?

Comment: Because my application is designed as a component for Nette PHP framework - it is simple file manager and I want workaround when exec using is disabled on server. Chunked copy is the best solution for my case I think.

Answer (score 1):

I would copy it  X byte by X byte (several megs each iteration).
X will be the most optimized size which depends on your machine.
And I would do it not through the web server but as a stand alone script, run through cron or one time call to it (cli).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy files from one server to another and you have ftp access on both of them, then you can simply use ftp 'put' command on source system and send the big file to the other system easily.