# PHP - Base64 Encode big files and write back synchronously

Tags: php, base64, synchronous

I need to base64 encode big file with PHP.
**file()** and **file_get_contents()** are not options since them loads whole file into memory.
I got idea to use this:

```
$handle = @fopen("/tmp/inputfile.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
        echo $buffer;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

SOURCE: [Read and parse contents of very large file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14848933/read-and-parse-contents-of-very-large-file)

This working well for reading, but is it possible to do it like this:
Read line -> base64 encode -> write back to file
And then repeat for each line in file.
Would be nice if it could do it directly, without need to write to temporary file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base64 encodes 3 bytes of raw data into 4 bytes on 7-bit safe text. If you feed it less than 3 bytes padding will occur, and you can't have that happen in the middle of the string. However, so long as you're dealing in multiples of 3 you're golden, sooo:

```
$base_unit = 4096;
$handle = @fopen("/tmp/inputfile.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($buffer = fread($handle, $base_unit*3)) !== false) {
        echo base64_encode($buffer);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Examples

Comment: It doesn't helps much since it doesn't write back to file in same time.
read line -> base64 encode line -> write line back

Comment: You cannot re-write a file in-place, you have to write it out to a new file and then change the name at the end.

Comment: Okay, that helps. Can I write to another file line by line in same time?

Comment: Yes, just open another handle.

Comment: Just a note--I would recommend using "fread()" in place of "fgets()", as the latter will stop at newline characters, causing unexpected behavior on many files.