# Php copy only copies part of file

Tags: php, file, copy

I am trying to copy a video file which has a size of 5Gbs.

I use this simple line:

```
copy($in, $out);
```

But somehow the copied file has only a size of ~700 Mb.

Is there a limit which the copy function has.

Are there some other ways to copy files using php?

Comment: Maybe this is usefull? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564643/copy-large-files-over-2-gb-in-php
In this it's suggested chunk it up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy large files (over 2 GB) in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564643/copy-large-files-over-2-gb-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I found a solution, I did following:

```
exec('copy ' $in . ' ' . $out);
```

This copied the whole file properly.

I am not sure why exactly this works.

My wild guess would be that `copy()` copies files immediately even if there a some changes and the command probably waits until there are no changes.