# PHP copy() is only copying half the image

Tags: php

https://trevim.pt/header-4/ 
I'm copying this image to this link 
https://trevim.pt/anuncios/header.png

When I run the script it always says 'File copied successfully' but some times I only get the top half of the image... it's not at all a large file (22.6KB), is this behavior normal? How can I copy the whole image every time? Any ideas? Here's my code:

```
foreach($to_activate as $data_row)
{
    $template_id = $data_row['template_id'];
    $img_url = $data_row['img_url'];
    $template = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT name FROM `wp_ad_templates` WHERE id = '$template_id' limit 1")->fetch_object()->name;

    $dst = "../" . $template . ".png";

    if(!@copy($img_url, $dst))
    {
        $errors= error_get_last();
        echo "COPY ERROR: ".$errors['type'];
        echo "<br>".$errors['message']."<br><br>";
    } else {
        echo "File copied from remote!";
    }
}
```

By the way I found this similar question [Php copy only copies part of file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41591247/php-copy-only-copies-part-of-file) which is solved by using `exec()` but that solution didn't work for me, I get:

`COPY ERROR: 2 
exec() has been disabled for security reasons`

Comment: When you don't have the `@` to suppress any errors in the `copy` do you get anything useful?

Comment: You could check the file size of the source image and then of the image after it's been copied, and if the sizes are not equal then you know it failed. I know that doesn't help you solve the `copy` problem, but at least you'd be able to better detect a failure.

Comment: Please refer the below URL https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php

Comment: I have `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning so the @ is there by mistake, it's removed now.